# How to send json syslog messages to a remote host with ulogd2

Tags: json, linux, rsyslog

I am working on a project to log connection tracking events with ulogd2. I want to know if there is any way to send messages to a remote host in JSON format. So far, I was able to save the message to a JSON file on the local server, but I don't want to save it in the local machine, I just want to send it. Or maybe if there is a way to send the file and after that delete it.
I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Usually syslog logs are sent to remote servers via one of the syslog network protocols, `rsyslog` is often used for this purpose. On the receiving end you can also use `rsyslog` to collect it into the syslog of the remote server.

On the receiving side you can also use tools like [fluentd](https://docs.fluentd.org/input/syslog) to collect the syslog messages and write them to a file as JSON or do a number of other tings with them. An alternative tool to do this as well is called [filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-syslog.html).

You can also install tools on the server creating the logs, instead of `rsyslog` which you can configure to send them via some method other than the syslog protocol if you so desire. Filebeat can do this and [fluent bit](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/inputs/syslog)(lightweight version of fluentd) as well.

Comment: Hi Caveman, thank you for your message and your help. Yes, I know how to send the message throught rsyslog, but the question was about ulogd, which allows to save the json file or send the message throught rsyslog in plane text.

Comment: @sebastianmontes sorry, my bad, I misunderstood. ulogd2 does not seem to be able to output JSON to anything other than a file. You can still use filebeat, fluentd or fluent bit, since all of them allow you to specify a file as input. When the log file updates they will consume the new line and send do something with them. In this case configuring logrotate for this log file might also be handy in case it becomes a lot

Comment: Yes! I did that. Thank you so much!